# Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is xxxx.xxx.xxx, real application class is null

Tags: java, android

I am in the process of implementing in app purchases into my app. Since google does not provide very friendly IAP API, I decided to use a library.

I get this following console error:
[image: 7t]

And the library fails to initialize as well (which I believe is due to this error) as my simple test shows:
[image]

How can I fix this error? I believe something is wrong in my AndroidManifest, so here is that file along with my classes:
[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste code and error messages here.

Comment: It is the first picture I have provided in the post.

Comment: As I said, you should copy and paste text here rather than post screenshots.